# get multiple times or filter id__in on a queryset which is more efficient in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Which of the following is more efficient in django if the length of `ids` is not big and the length of `queryset` might be too large?

```py
items = [item for item in queryset.filter(id__in=ids)]
```

```py
items = [queryset.get(id=id) for id in ids]
```

N.B: it's guaranteed that there is no such id that will mismatch. Also there might be several cases where length of ids is 1

Answer (score 2):

The query that uses `.filter(…)` will be more efficient: this will perform *one* query on the database, whereas the solution with `.get(…)` will run *n* queries on the database, with *n* the number of elements in `ids`.

While that `.filter(…)` query might take a bit longer, constructing the query, sending the query to the database, decoding the query, constructing an execution plan, and sending the result back will all be done once with `.filter(…)`, whereas for the `.get(…)` solution, this will be done *n* times.

Note that the two are semantically not equivalent: the `.filter(…)` will retrieve all items for which an `id` exists, the `.get(…)` solution on the other hand will error in case it can not find an id.

In case the number of items to return is huge, you should *not* store these in a list, but work with an [**`.iterator(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) to process the items in chunks, so:

```
for item in queryset.filter(id__in=ids).iterator():
    # do something …
```

If you would store the items in a list, that would defeat the purpose of the iterator, since then all objects are all "alive" at the same time, and thus there should be enough memory to keep these in memory.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to measure the efficiency then we have to think about the query at first. Because both are doing list comprehension and we have nothing to do with that.

Now if we come to the `queryset.filter` and `queryset.get` and try to understand the equivalent SQL query.

- SQL query count: For `filter` there will be only one query but for `get` there will be `n` number of query. Even if the `n` is 2, `filter` is more efficient than `get`.
- Execution efficiency: This one also relay on SQL query. Because as the `get` implementation says it will create query and perform it each time. But `filter` will create a single query and perform it for one time. And transnational execution(Making a query to DB) is always slower than doing it in the code.

You can see the SQL query of `queryset.filter` by printing the `query` attribute of it.

I think `filter` is more efficient than `get` in this case.

Comment: As I know filtering is something like searching inside queryset, what if the length of queryset gets too large than the length of ids?

Comment: Here is the magic of filter comes. It doesn't pull all the value from database. It creates a WHERE ... LIKE query and pull only those values from DB. Think it as a SQL query not a python searching algorithm. Suppose if you had to do it using query, What you would do. You will create a WHERE ... LIKE query to the DB and pull all the values once at a time right?